# Powershells Copy-Item in Ansible

Tags: powershell, ansible

I have a problem with ansible. I need to copy something from one computer in network onto host machine (windows) using ansible task.

I had tested many diffrent approach, including powerscript file as ansible task, and using `win_shell` to directly include powershells CMD-lets.

In every case, when i call Copy-Item directly on host machine in Powershell window, everything works fine. But after calling it by Ansible i got

```
Copy-Item : Cannot find path '//[ip]/[path]/[file]' because it does not exist.
```

When im logging to host machine i'm using the same user both in ansible and in remote desktop connection.

Has anyone idea what can going on?

ansible task:

```
  - name: Install 7Zip
    win_shell: |
      $path = '//[ip]/[path]/[file]'
      Copy-Item $path -Destination "C:/[Location]"
    tags:
      - 7zip
```

`[ip]`,`[path]`,`[file]`, and `[location]` are just mocks i put on SO to avoid bothering you all with Polish folder names and my intranet IP.

In powershell command in exactly the same as in ansible:

```
PS C:\Users\ansibler> $path = '//[ip]/[path]/[file]'
PS C:\Users\ansibler> Copy-Item $path -Destination "[location]"
```

Comment: what are `[ip]` `[path]` `[file]` and `[location]` ? are they variables, do you use that litteraly ? You shoudl also provide the command you use directly that work for comparison. Please [edit] the question to add those information.

Comment: @BaptisteMille-Mathias  done

Comment: A further step to debug would be to register the task and debug the output and add this to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, i solve it.

double hop was a problem. Solution was to use "ansible_become" and re-authenticate user in host machine:

```
vars:
  ansible_become: yes
  ansible_become_method: runas
  ansible_become_flags: logon_type=new_credentials logon_flags=netcredentials_only
  ansible_become_user: [login]
  ansible_become_pass: [password]
```

Comment: @Tom - I'll do that, but it can be done after two day from posting self-answer ;).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use UNC path, UNC path uses backslash.

```
- name: Install 7Zip
    win_shell: |
      $path = '\\[ip]\[path]\[file]'
      Copy-Item $path -Destination "C:/[Location]"
    tags:
      - 7zip
```

the best way to copy file is to use `win_copy` module.

```
- name: Install 7Zip
    win_copy:
      src: '\\[ip]\[path]\[file]'
      dest: "C:\[Location]"
      remote_src: True
```

Update:

The error you got is because of the double hop here. I can show you a workaround by mapping a drive before attempting a copy, this work arounds the double hopping issues.

```
- name: Install 7Zip
    win_shell: |
      net use \\[ip]\[path] password /user:username 2>&1
      $path = '\\[ip]\[path]\[file]'
      Copy-Item $path -Destination "C:/[Location]"
    tags:
      - 7zip
```

Comment: the output is the same, despite of direction of slashes

Comment: did you try `win_copy` ?. When accessing from remote share, PowerShell will have to handle double hop, hence `win_copy` is recommended

Comment: Yes, i have try. Effect is the same:  `"module_stderr": "Exception calling \"Run\" with \"1\" argument(s): \"Exception calling \"Invoke\" with \r\n\"0\" argument(s): \"The running command stopped because the preference variable \"\r\nErrorActionPreference\" or common parameter is set to Stop: Access is denied\"\"\r\nAt line:65 char:5\r\n+     $output = $entrypoint.Run($payload)\r\n+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordE \r\n   xception\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptMethodRuntimeException\r\n \r\n"`

Comment: Could you register the command you posted in the question and debug it and attach the tasks execution in the question ?

Comment: Never worked that way, even with UNC.
I'm posting my working example.  Thx to all for the references

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked in this way:

```
 - name: Run Shell Copy Cmd
   win_shell: Copy-Item '\\remote\public\foo\*' C:\Windows\Temp\bar
   become: yes
   become_method: runas
   become_user: vagrant
   vars:
     ansible_become_password: "pass"
```

I tried the same with the `win_copy` module, but could never make it work